# foreign_key :country_id must be distinct from corresponding association name

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

When i run mix ecto.migrate I encountered an error, `(ArgumentError) foreign_key :country_id must be distinct from corresponding association name lib/ecto/schema.ex:1499: Ecto.Schema.__belongs_to__/4`

My goal is i want to add two foreign keys in my mobiles table, which is conutry_id and country_code. What I am missing?

This is my mobiles schema:

```
schema "mobiles" do
field :number, :string

belongs_to :person, Person.Person
belongs_to :country_id, Person.Country, foreign_key: :country_id
belongs_to :country_code, Person.Country, foreign_key: :country_code
has_many :mobile_audits, Person.MobileAudit, on_delete: :delete_all

timestamps()
end
```

This is my countries schema:

```
schema "countries" do
field :code, :string
field :name, :string
field :iso_codes, :string

has_many :mobiles, Person.Mobile, on_delete: :delete_all

timestamps()
end
```

And this is my migration script:

```
def change do
alter table(:mobiles) do
  add :country_id, references(:countries, type: :binary_id, column: :id)
  add :country_code, references(:countries, type: :string, column: :code)
end
end
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
belongs_to :country_id, Person.Country, foreign_key: :country_id
```

This macro call is in the form `belongs_to :name, QueryAbleModuleName, opts`. Now in your case, the `:name` argument and the `foreign_key` option has the same value. Generally, the `foreign_key` should be `<name>_id`.

If the table has `company_id` field, then the call should look like:

```
belongs_to :company, MyModule.Company, foreign_key: :company_id
```

So if you want `country_id` and `country_code` as association names, consider making the foreign keys `country_id_id` and `country_code_id` and make sure your database schema reflects that.

Or think about something more meaningful in your context.